# How to tell whether my Newsstand Atom Feed will be processed or not?

Tags: ios, atom-feed, newsstand-kit

EDIT:2013-06-11: I mean that Is it a way to confirm Newsstand Atom feeds are without corrupting now woking hand filling Newsstand items. When I posted this question, I want to test the atom feed for an already released app, but I was afraid that current Newsstand Item (added by hand) displayed on App Store could be deleted. So I tried to test the same atom feed  on another dummy app on iTunes Connect, but I was not sure it is OK because Newsstand items in the atom feed are not shown in iTunes Connect...

I set an URL to an Atom feed and wait 24h (3 days now), but issues from Atom feed doesn't seem to appear in "Manage Newsstand" in iTunes Connect.
**I have tested this for an unreleased app**. So I don't know those issues from an Atom feed will apear in App Store.
Is it correct behavior? Do anybody use an atom feed for updating issues?

FYI, I quoted notes on "Atom feed" settings:

> Feed information is processed once a day. After adding or updating
>   your feed you may need to wait 24 hours before the change will be
>   visible in iTunes Connect and/or on the App Store. For more
>   information, refer to the Newsstand Atom Feed Specification.

P.S. I'm sorry about cross posting this question with https://devforums.apple.com/thread/147608, but the topic on the forum seems to be desolated...

update: The feed is validated at the time I enter the URL (I corrected some errors).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed all the requirements specified in https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/NewsstandAtomFeedSpecification.pdf

Especially, the xml tags have to be organised as specified. One of the reasons for the cover art icon not being updated will be incorrect dimensions of the image. This icon must be at least 1024px on the long side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah there are restrictions, and if there is an error, iTunes connect show us an error on setting atom feed urls. I edited the question as adding my intention of the question.